# Curious how a server works

Tags: server, application-development, webserver

I am currently a high school student who has developed a few iPhone apps that have connected to Parse.com, so I have a little idea of how a... "server" (pre-made) works. But, I do know that's not how a server is built from the ground up and there is more to that.

My question is, how does a server actually work? Is it basically an operating system? What's the difference between running a server with Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server?

And my biggest, biggest question that I can't seem to find the answer to is: where do you put the code you write? How would I replicate Parse.com on a real server with a database and iPhone API's?

Talking high-level conceptual, if I wanted to write an extremely basic app that communicated with a server, how would I do so? For example, let's say I have an iPhone or web app that asked for the users name. When it get's the users name, I want to send it to the server, and respond back "Hello, [user's name]!" (I know I could do this very easily within Swift or Javascript on the actual app, but for demo purposes.) How would I go about doing that with server set up, connecting to the server, getting a response back in the app, and where to put that code on the server that would respond back to the app?

I apologize if this is the wrong place or a basic question, but I cannot seem to find the key answers that I have been itching to have answered anywhere online. I'm dying to know the concepts. I'm a very curious and independent learned, but just don't know conceptually where to start.

Thank you so much in advance for your help. Again, I am so curious to know and find out about this.

Alex, a curious high school student.

Comment: What you are asking about is a "web"server. "server" in itself is not possible to explain since it includes databaseservers, printservers,  mailservers.

Comment: To be fair, the word "server" is one of the most overloaded terms in devops, computer science, and software development. "When the server started up, the server did not start, so we had to log into the server to restart the server."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how does a server actually work?

Workflow for a webserver as an example:

- Desktop (Ubuntu desktop installation)

  - Browser

    - URL contains a domain and parameters
    - Waits till results arrives and shows them
- Computer that has this domain (Ubuntu server installation)

  - Webserver (Apache)

    - Program that gets parameters and executes it. Does what it needs to do (create website, content, show a form etc). Could be in combination with a database (MySQL), a coding language (Python, Perl, Javascript).
    - Send results to desktop

> Is it basically an operating system?

Ehm. No. Ubuntu is the operating system. What makes it a server is the fact you install server software onto it and set it up. Like hosting a website you do with Apache (= webserver). In combination you can also add or have a database (MySQL; databaseserver) or a mailsystem (=mailserver).

> What's the difference between running a server with Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server?

None whatsoever. You can remove the "desktop" component and have a "server". You can use a "desktop" to install server software like a webserver, printserver, databaseserver, mailserver, template server and so on and call it a server.

> How would I go about doing that with server set up

- Ubuntu has a setup that installs it all and creates a basic setup for you using your desktop machine. `sudo apt-get install lampserver^` will install the Linux version for Apache, Mysql, Perl and set it up for you such that you can point your browser to `http://localhost` and it will show a website with "ItWorks!" on it.

[image]

- If you want this to work remotely you need to purchase a domain, receive an IP adress (and a name for that IP) and then you can use that IP or that name instead of localhost.

Comment: Thank you so much for the great answer! How would I go about making the HTML side that connects to a program, say in Python, on the Web Server? Where would I put the python file, how would I connect into the python file from html via the server, etc.?

Answer (score 2):

> What's the difference between running a server with Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server?

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ServerFaq

> Since 12.04, there is no difference in kernel between Ubuntu Desktop and Ubuntu Server since Linux-image-server is merged into Linux-image-generic.

However, Ubuntu Server wouldn't have the unnecessary desktop elements making it more efficient to serve a website or database.

> Is it basically an operating system?

It is not an operating system. Though, it is built on the top of an operating system. An operating system is the pre-requisite of making a server(obviously). And there is no compulsion on the OS. It can be Windows or Ubuntu. Whatever you want to use.

> My question is, how does a server actually work?

You will get a better understanding of how a server works if you make your own desktop machine a server. For Ubuntu, the following command will work like a charm and you will end up with a server.

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

You can host a website(HTTP), serve a database(MYSQL) or even files(FTP). Once you have it you can play around with it and explore options.

Good luck!